# SORT BY DATE sqlite does not work like normal sql? can I use php function to sort?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, model-view-controller

I am using an sqLite database in which I have a table called "calender".

This table contains the following columns:

```
 id           -INTEGER
 titel        -VARCHAR
 beschrijving -VARCHAR
 datum        -DATETIME
 inhoud       -TEXT
 album        -VARCHAR
```

Anyway: I am storing my dates like this: "03-01-2015" So thats: d - m - Y.

However when I run my sqlQuery to select them I cannot use ORDER BY datum. This does not order them. The sql function `STR_TO_DATE('datum','%d,%m,%Y')` doesn't seem to exist either in sqLite and returns an error "no such function". (I am not even saving dates as a string though but as actual DATETIMES, so this is not the problem.)

Anyways I am showing the data from my table like this:

```
 while ($x = $resultGetAllCalender->fetchObject()){
    $html .="    
      <div class='col-md-4'>             
          <div class='col-sm-10 kalenderTopic'>
              <div class='datum'><strong>Datum: <span>$x->datum</span></div>
              <div class='datum'>Activiteit: <span>$x->titel</span></div>
              <div class='inhoud'>$x->beschrijving</div>
              <div class='readMore'><a href='index.php?page=kalenderDetail&id=$x->id'>Meer informatie</a>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Finally I echo out my $html later.

Maybe I can sort the result of $resultGetAllCalender->FetchObject() first (using a php function like  usort()) Before running a while loop to add all my data to my $html variable.

However I am confused I cant seem to sort result of my fetch either.

**Edit:** My method that contains the query: (I am no longer using any ORDER BY since this was not working.)

```
 public function getAllKalender(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM kalender";
        $statement = $this->makeStatement($sql); 
        return $statement;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your full query also please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a custom string to sort with in the SQL query using `substr()`:

```
substr(datum,7)||substr(datum,4,2)||substr(datum,1,2)
```

What this does is grabbing portions of the `datum` field and putting it together in way that makes it sortable: `Ymd`

### Live example

Take a look at this fiddle for a live example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/de165/1

### Example query

```
SELECT * FROM calender ORDER BY substr(datum,7)||substr(datum,4,2)||substr(datum,1,2) ASC;
```

Comment: I almost had it! I just figured out I indeed needed them to be in YMD in order to sort them, thank you so much!